# Automatically add additional file name extensions into plist for Emacs?

Tags: automation, plist, auto-update

My Emacs is regularly updated by Homebrew along with other apps. How do I automatically add Markdown file name extension to its plist file (/Applications/Emacs.app/Contents/Info.plist) so Emacs appear in the list of apps in the Open With menu for Markdown files?

```
<dict>
    <key>CFBundleTypeExtensions</key>
    <array>
        <string>markdown</string>
        <string>md</string>
    </array>
</dict>
```

Comment: You need to be careful that editing the Info.plist doesn’t break the code-signing.